# jQuery Detect Value In Text Field From Paste Immediately Not Later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery and currently have code that looks like the following:

```
$('body').children("#desktop").on('keyup paste',".password",function(){
        //Check characters to make sure more than 6
        $('#desktop').find('.errormessage_password').remove('');
        $('#desktop').find('.password_area').append('<div class="errormessage_password"></div>');
        $('#desktop').find('.errormessage_password').html('<div class="bad">'+$(this).val()+'</div>');
});
```

Right now I print to the screen what the value of the password area is just for demo purposes.  It works for characters that are typed and I immediately can see the characters, therefore I can count it later.

My problem is when I paste (and using control-v), but (rightclick->paste), it will not be able to get the data from password field.

How do I detect a paste event **after** the paste has occured **not before**.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, looks like I was using the wrong events.

Use

```
$('body').children("#desktop").on('input propertychange',".password",function(){
```

Notice input and propertychange.  After some reading these detect character input changes and for that matter any input change including pasting.